# Black WinForms button

Tags: .net, button, custom-controls, gdi+

What is the most straightforward way to add a black button with white text in a WinForms Application? Simply setting the BackColor to black and the ForeColor to white the button border remains as before.

Do I need to subclass the System.Windows.Forms.Button class and take control of the OnPaint() drawing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `FlatStyle` property to `FlatStyle.Flat`.

You can use the `FlatAppearance` property to further modify the L&F.

Comment: Try one of the other FlatStyles.